# What is actual pixels against text size list in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, web

What is the actual font size in pixels against following text size list in IE:

- Largest
- Larger
- Medium
- Smaller
- Smallest

In a web application, I need to provide similiar behavior to set the text size of application control by selection anyone from above list. But, how much pixels I need to set programmatically against selected item from this list.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't - the IE font-size setting is not exposed to web applications unless you're hosting the `WebBrowser` control within a desktop application. Even if you override the default font-size using CSS, it has no bearing on IE's size setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the current style with Javascript, using this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test font size</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="test">This is a test</p>
    <script>
      var elem = document.getElementById('test');
      elem.innerHTML = 'The font size is '+elem.currentStyle.fontSize;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(or if you're too lazy to copy and paste all that, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kMBPn/))

results in this list:

- Text size Largest: 16pt (= 21.3px)
- Text size Larger: 14pt (= 18.7px)
- Text size Medium: 12pt (= 16px)
- Text size Smaller: 10pt (= 13.3px)
- Text size Smallest: 9pt (= 12px)

Note: after you change the text size, refresh the screen (or re-run the fiddle) to make the script update the text.
Another note: currentStyle is a proprietary property that works only with IE.
And a final note: I calculated the pixel values based on a DPI of 96; don't know if the results are different on monitors with other DPI values, so use with care.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) :

The following table provides **user agent guidelines** for the absolute-size mapping to HTML heading and absolute font-sizes. The 'medium' value is the user's preferred font size and is used as the reference middle value.

```
HTML Values : xx-small  x-small  small  medium  large  x-large  xx-large     
Font sizes  : 1         -        2      3       4      5        6
```

The relative values would follow the table to go larger, smaller (depending on the context) :

> Possible values are: [ larger | smaller ]. For example, if the parent
>   element has a font size of 'medium', a value of 'larger' will make the
>   font size of the current element be 'large'. If the parent element's
>   size is not close to a table entry, the UA is free to interpolate
>   between table entries or round off to the closest one. The UA may have
>   to extrapolate table values if the numerical value goes beyond the
>   keywords.

---

Note that these are simply the guidelines to be followed by the browser & in no way guarantees the sizes in IE. But I believe it does give an idea for what you are looking for.